# What's the proper way to initialize instance attributes that refer to files?

Tags: python

So for a variety of reason, I have a class that uses several sub-files to write into and to read from. I'm wondering what's the proper way to initialize a object attribute in `__init__`. As files are just the path to file as string, I have chosen to initialize them as `self.file = 'file'`. This feels very dirty to me for some reason, and I'm sure this is going against some kind of convention. I'm guessing that `self.metafile = None` might be a popular convention but really not sure about that.

A simple example (with only two object attribute files, in some cases I'm working with 5-6 of them). (I realise that in this case it would not be absolutely necessery to use them as object attributes, but I've found that it really helps me in the real work that I'm doing, and I'm mostly here for the semantics of how to initialize the file in the first place.)

```
class FileHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, source, meta):
        self.source_folder = source
        self.meta_folder = meta
        self.metafile = 'file'
        self.output = 'file'

    def read_meta(self):
        meta = glob.glob(self.meta_folder+ '*.csv')
        for m in meta:
            self.metafile = m
            self.read_data()   

    def read_data(self):
        source = glob.glob(self.source_folder + '*.csv')
        for src in source:
            current_file = src.strip('.csv')
            if current_file == self.metafile.strip('_meta.csv')
                self.output = current_file + '_output.csv'
                self.combine_meta()

    def combine_meta(self):
        # reads the source data, combines it with metadata and writes out
        # a neat csv file (to self.output) that can be imported into a database
```

Comment: Btw, why do you store the last `metafile` and `output` in both loops? Is there a situation in which you would have several metafiles or several outputs?

Comment: Yes, there can be dozens of each in some cases.

Comment: May be you can leave `metafile` and `output` as local variables in functions. Then pass `metafile` as argument to `read_data` and both `metafile` and `output` to `combine_meta`. That way you will not need to initialize them. Of course, this all will work, unless you use them in other methods too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, generally I would set `metafile` and `output` to `None` in the constructor.

```
class FileHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, source, meta):
        self.source_folder = source
        self.meta_folder = meta
        self.metafile = None
        self.output = None

....
```

It allows you to test if the corresponding file has been initialized, just by checking it for Truth. Eg:

```
if self.metafile:
    ....
```